# Force system to always ask for wifi password

Tags: wi-fi, security

I use my institutional credentials to connect to my work wifi network (using 802.1x EAP), and I don't want my password stored on my phone (i.e. I want to retype my password every time I connect). What's the best way to do this? A Google Pixel running stock 7.1, if that matters.

Comment: do you want to do it for a specific wifi of your institute or all wifi to which you connect from phone?

Comment: Would be nice if it could be wifi-specific, but I don't terribly mind forcing it for all wifi if need be.

Comment: I don't yet own Pixel device hence can't exactly say if it offers settings for what you want. But the easy way that comes to my mind is, & it is far from perfect, but may serve your purpose is this : **Just forgot your work wifi network when you are done.** That way any credentials that may have saved will be cleard. Next day when you turn on wifi, and try to connect to your work wifi network your phone will ask you to enter wifi password

Answer (score 1):

If you are rooted you could just run the command `chmod 0440 /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Before you do it you should first delete the WiFi network. Also make sure that you have all other WiFi networks saved because after you ran this command you won't save any other network again until you chmodded the file to r+w again.